# The font-rendering in Mint 15 / Cinnamon looks too light

Tags: linux, fonts, gnome, linux-mint, cinnamon

So I tried some ways.

I installed my favorite font (a bind of MS-Yahei and Consolas), and it looks light and not clean on the screen. Compared to my previous choice Xubuntu, the font on Xubuntu looks very solid.

I tried to use `fontconfig-infinality`, but MDM failed to show during system start with infinality installed and enabled (well, not sure what "enabled" is, but got its .sh file in /etc/profile.d) -- I have to login in to the tty and use `startx` to get the desktop environment. When I removed infinality, MDM came back.

Also, there isn't a GUI utility for infinality, is there? It's hard to compare and choose the best configuration.

BTW, when using Cinnamon's font settings, the `RGB` and `Greyscale` for `Antialiasing` show no difference. `Medium` and `Full` for `Hinting` show no difference either. For `RGB` and `Greyscale`, I tried the work around mentioned in http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=200&t=99945 -- simlink the file from `conf.avail` to `conf.d`. However, I didn't see any effect when I did it.

BTW2, in Mint 15, there is no `.font.conf` in `~`.

So, is there any way to get the solid font rendering like the Xubuntu's in Mint 15 / Cinnamon?

Comment: Please include screenshots, we really have no idea what you're describing.

Comment: @terdon in a word: two problems. First: after installing fontconfig-infinality, I can't use MDM (that is to say, it can't get to the gui login screen, but a tty instead). Sceond: choosing the `RGB` and `Greyscale` for Antialiasing in font-setting or gnome-tweak-tool shows no difference - the font effect for these two options looks all the same.